# Auto fill stub parameters for constructors in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor, autocomplete

Does Intellij have any way of auto-creating constructor calls, based on the parameters from the constructor's signature?

The idea is that I type the name of class (constructor name), hit <kbd>Magic</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>+<kbd>Combination</kbd>, choose the relevant constructor, and IntelliJ types in all the parameters, based on the names in the constructor's signature. Obviously, in most cases, that wouldn't compile but that's OK, as I will create the required parameters with the appropriate names.

An even better idea would be for the feature to also create the parameter definitions for me, right above the constructor call.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JetBrains support, this feature is not supported (current latest version of IntelliJ is 14.1).

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Eclipse user recently migrated into IntelliJ and that was one of the features I really missed, esp. when there are calls with many parameters (not just constructors). As long as there are matching variables in scope, ctrl-shift-space is somewhat similar. It's not quite as good as in Eclipse because if the variables are not there it will not create "stubs", and I don't think it works if the parameter names don't match, but works as a crutch in at least some cases...

Answer (score 0):

In intellij, I cannot autogenerate but the shortcut in mac is
<kbd>OPTION</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The use case I was looking for, when the question was posted, required an auto-fill of parameter. Your answer has constants.

Answer (score 0):

This still isn't possible just using IntelliJ, but there is a plugin that adds this feature for Kotlin: https://github.com/suusan2go/kotlin-fill-class